# Is Azure Data Factory Data Flow Joins case sensitive?

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are trying to join two tables (Azure SQL tables) together and it appears that the Join function in ADF Data Flow is case sensitive.  When we join the table directly to each other it doesn't return all 11155 rows that are in the table, however if we run a simple select statement in SQL Management studio all 11155 rows are returned.  If I add a derived column step that performs a "Lower()" on the field before the join statement for the source table and also a derived column step for the table being joined I get all 11155 rows.

Thoughts on how to avoid adding the derived column steps to ensure my joins work properly.

My expectations is the join will match the tables on the column regardless of case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **joins in ADF dataflows are Case sensitive** and not same as SQL joins. You need the same case columns to perform the join.

> Thoughts on how to avoid adding the derived column steps to ensure my joins work properly.

If you want to avoid the derived column step, you can try the **Custom cross** join. Select Custom cross join and specify the condition.

```
lower(source1@Name)==source2@Name
```

or
you can convert both columns to lower.

```
lower(source1@Name)==lower(source2@Name)
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

But as per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join#:%7E:text=The%20Spark%20engine,then%20filter%20rows.), This might slow the performance of the dataflow if the data is large.

So, based on your data, you can use this method or use derived column method.